# List Contains by field

Tags: c#, list

I wanted to know the best way (non-LINQ and LINQ) to test if a list contains an element by it's field value.

```
public class A
{
    public B bField;
}

public class B {}

List<A> listA = new List<A> ();
B someB = new B();
listA.Contains(someB)
```

Comment: there are not many ways, google for some first

Answer (score 7):

The non-Linq approach, a simple loop:

```
bool contains = false;
foreach(A a in listA)
{
    if(someB.Equals(a.bField))
    {
        contains = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

The Linq approach, using `Enumerable.Any`:

```
contains = listA.Any(a => someB.Equals(a.bField));
```

Note that you need to override `Equals` in a meaningful way.

Comment: @DonBoitnott: why not?

Comment: @zerkms Withdrawn due to edit, but the reason what that they weren't the same type.

Comment: @DonBoitnott: even if they are of a different type - `Equals` accepts an `Object` so it's up to you how to implement their comparison

Comment: @zerkms I respond to what _is_ there, not what _might someday_ be there.

Comment: @DonBoitnott: i've already edited my answer. I've forgotten to use the `bField` in the first version.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Noted, and critique was withdrawn, as I said.

Comment: @abatishchev: because it's more likely that someone overrides `Equals` instead of overloading the `==` operator. The `B` class has no properties so i cannot show how to override `Equals` meaningfully. I assume that OP actually uses a more complex class ;)

Comment: Thank you! and yes I do occasionally write more complex classes ;)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
listA.Any(x => x.bField == someB);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant:

```
listA.Any( x=> x.bField == someB);
```